# Can you switch BIOSes while the system is powered on/running?

Tags: bios

I have the MSI X79A-GD65 (8D) motherboard. It has two BIOSes - BIOS A and BIOS B and a BIOS Switch.
BIOS A got corrupted somehow due to failed BIOS update going from v1.8 to v4.8. Now I am using BIOS B (v1.8).

The version 1.8 BIOS update is updated through MS-DOS boot mode
The version 4.8 BIOS update is done through running the windows executable from a USB flash drive. This BIOS update will update both BIOS and the "Intel ME Firmware". Does the intel ME firmware also reside on the BIOS?

However I tried the instructions in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66zSBpkvxEU
It worked, BIOS A's flash got rewritten to v1.8, however I tried booting the system with BIOS A but it only turned itself on and off.

I am wondering if it is possible to update BIOS A again while booted into windows in BIOS B. Someone mentioned in a comment in that youtube video that the method works. I will flip the BIOS Switch from BIOS B to BIOS A while I am logged into Windows and then run the executable from the USB flash drive. If I do this, BIOS B should remain unaffected and it will only affect BIOS A?

Comment: Does MSI document this process anywhere? The implementation of this function will require MSI software or hardware integration to support switching while Windows is running.

Comment: Intel ME is a feature of the CPU so it’s likely partially microcode ; “ I tried booting the system with BIOS A but it only turned itself on and off.” - sounds like the firmware is corrupted; I wouldn’t chance corruption of the firmware doing what you suggest

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was able to switch BIOS. Did the leap of faith myself and it worked. The video itself demonstrates that it is possible to switch the active BIOS while your system is powered on: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66zSBpkvxEU

Note that since I tried it on MSI motherboards, then I can only attest that it works without errors on MSI motherboards with Dual bioses and a BIOS switch. It may or may not work for other brands of boards with Dual bioses and a bios switch.

Furthermore, I was able to recover the BIOS A to a working state and then update it to the latest version (v4.8). I now have 2 working BIOSes.